# Magento 2.4.2 WYSIWYG Editor is SO Narrow

Tags: wysiwyg, blog

I have a website I'm helping a client populate content. I'm trying to create blog posts but the WYSIWYG editor is SO narrow making it hard to update content. I've attached an image. Anyone know how to modify this?

I have a bit of coding experience but any help would be greatly appreciated. Screen cap below:

[image]

Comment: This is because you have those much layout and space there.

Comment: How do I move change it?